# Run unit tests in all projects, even if some fail

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle

I have a multi module Gradle project. I want it to compile and do all other tasks as normal. But for unit tests, I want it to run all of them, instead of stopping as soon as one test in an early project fails.

I've tried adding

```
buildscript {
    gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
}
```

which works for the tests, but also makes compile continue if something fails. That's not OK.

Can I configure Gradle to continue, only for test tasks?

Comment: would doing `gradle jar && gradle test` work?

Comment: I'll look into that. Perhaps `gradle test --continue` and another step to build the artifact (e.g. `gradle jar`) will have the desired effect.

Comment: did you manage to do it Jorn ?

Comment: In my case, I just need to add `--continue` for `gradle test` (`gradle test --continue`) and it works

Answer (score 3):

I changed @LazerBanana answer to cancel next tasks after test fail.

Usually all publishing starts after all tests (as an example - Artifactory plugin does this). So, instead of build failure, it is better to add global task, which will be between tests and publishing (or run).
So, your task sequence should be like this:

1. Compile each project
2. Test each project
3. Collect test results on the all project and fail the build
4. Publish artifacts, notify user, etc.

Additional items:

1. I avoid using Ant Fail. There is GradleException for this purpose
2. testCheck task executes all code in doLast section, as recommended by gradle

Code:

```
ext.testFailures = 0 //set a global variable to hold a number of failures

task testCheck() {
    doLast {
        if (testFailures > 0) {
            message = "The build finished but ${testFailures} tests failed - blowing up the build ! "
            throw new GradleException(message)
        }
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->

    taskGraph.allTasks.each { task -> //get all tasks
        if (task.name == "test") { //filter it to test tasks only

            task.ignoreFailures = true //keepgoing if it fails
            task.afterSuite { desc, result ->
                if (desc.getParent() == null) {
                    ext.testFailures += result.getFailedTestCount() //count failures
                }
            }

            testCheck.dependsOn(task)
        }
    }
}    

// add below tasks, which are usually executed after tests
// as en example, here are build and publishing, to prevent artifacts upload
// after failed tests
// so, you can execute the following line on your build server:
// gradle artifactoryPublish
// So, after failed tests publishing will cancelled
build.dependsOn(testCheck)
artifactoryPublish.dependsOn(testCheck)
distZip.dependsOn(testCheck)
configureDist.dependsOn(testCheck)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in main `build.gradle` and let me know, I have tested that with a small pmultiproject and seems to do what you need.

```
ext.testFailures = 0 //set a global variable to hold a number of failures

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->

    taskGraph.allTasks.each { task -> //get all tasks
        if (task.name == "test") { //filter it to test tasks only

            task.ignoreFailures = true //keepgoing if it fails
            task.afterSuite { desc, result ->
                if (desc.getParent() == null) {
                    ext.testFailures += result.getFailedTestCount() //count failures
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

gradle.buildFinished { //when it finishes check if there are any failures and blow up

    if (ext.testFailures > 0) {
        ant.fail("The build finished but ${ext.testFailures} tests failed - blowing up the build ! ")
    }

}
```

Comment: No, I still want the whole build to fail if tests fail.

Comment: @Jorn I see, then you want everything run but the build failing when the test failed? I thought this is how it's implemented by default? you can still ignore failures and implement a test listener and fail the build if there was any tests failed. i WIll update an answer later.

Comment: `then you want everything run but the build failing when the test failed`. More or less, yes. The default behavior is to stop building as soon as any task fails. I want to do that, except for a submodule test task, so that I get as much information as possible. When compiling fails, it makes no sense to continue. When a test fails, it does make sense to run more tests, but not to deploy an artifact.

Comment: @Jorn i have updated the question, gonna test it as well but maybe it will work straight away, please check and tell me if something is not working